# How to refresh ViewController targeted with Back Button

Tags: ios, swift2

I have a localized app that runs well.  While all pages refresh with the change language button, their is one page that does not.  This page is triggered by a "Back" button.  Apparently, Back buttons do not trigger the function ViewDidLoad.  How to refresh a VC as the result of a Back Button?

Comment: And so, this issue has been resolved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the code you want inside: `viewWillAppear:` method.

Comment: Yes, it has. Thanks for your support